# dividing nodes into threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I have an output calculating program that, given the amount of nodes (n = 5) in the mxn matrix, generates the output of the nodes until convergence is reached within the amout of iterations (iterations = 100).

I want to have 2 threads, so 1 thread will calculate 3 nodes, and the second will calculate 2 nodes.
Currently my program divides the iterations into 2 and runs my calculating program in both rather than divide the calculations between them, giving me the outputs twice which takes longer than just running a single thread.

```
void calculations() {
  //do matrix calculations
  double matrix[n][n] = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} };
  double results = {1,2,3,4,5};
  ...
  //print calculations here
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
  //multi thread calculations
  thread* threads[2];
  for (int proc = 0; proc < 2s; proc++) {
      threads[proc] = new thread(calculations);
  }
  for (thread *t : threads) {
      t->join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

How would I write this to divide the calculations in the threads rather than just output the program twice? I assume I will need sperate thread methods?

Comment: Which data do you want your first thread to work on, and which will your second thread work on?

Comment: I have no idea from this question what a node is, or what the calculation is. This means I have no way to tell whether the threads are completely independent, or are supposed to interact or share data. In general, you can have a single thread function and pass different arguments to it instead of hardcoding magic numbers in two versions of the same function.

Comment: Not clear, as far as I understand a node is one line in your matrix is it true, if this is the case what is calculating one node ?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] ... one that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a snippet to return two leaf nodes from two threads using std::tuple ( you can change to output 2-3 leaf nodes). Since a thread cannot return a value to the calling program, you can use std::future in conjunction with std:promise to do so ( code  is self explanatory).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

void node_calc(promise<tuple<double,double>>& p)
{
    tuple<double,double> result; 
    //result = calculate here
    result = std::make_tuple(10,100);
    p.set_value(result);
}

int main()
{    
    thread threads[2];
    vector<future<tuple<double,double>>> future_results;

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        promise<tuple<double,double>> p ;
        future<tuple<double,double>> f = p.get_future();
        threads[i] = thread( [&]() { node_calc(p); } );
        future_results.push_back(std::move(f));
    }

    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();

    vector<double> results;
    for(auto& f:future_results)
    {   
        tuple<double,double> t = f.get();
        results.push_back(std::get<0>(t));
        results.push_back(std::get<1>(t));
    }

    for(auto result:results)
    {
        cout << result <<" ";
    }

}
```

Test Output

[image]

Comment: I would use `std::array<double,2>`. BTW, `main()` is also running in a thread.